# Meteor Reactive Table Helper Arguments

Tags: meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

Using the latest version of Meteor with aslagle:reactive-table.

In Iron Router, I can pass a data context to my template:

router.js:

```
Router.route('/dates', {
  name: 'dates',
  data: {
    header_title: 'Dates & Times'
  }
});
```

dates.html:

```
<div class="bt-h1">{{header_title}}</div>
```

Can I do something similar with ReactiveTables, i.e. pass "variable" from router.js?

```
{{> reactiveTable collection=tests settings=variable}}
```

Comment: Just to add, tried {{> reactiveTable collection=tests settings={{variable}}}} but get a syntax error.

Comment: Try the variable without the {{ }} and also try ../variable where ../ refers to the parent data context (the route template).