# Pass argument to collection in meteor reactive-table

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am using package `aslagle:reactive-table`

I want to pass an argument to the `collection` option of the reactive table

I have checked this also [Meteor Reactive Table Helper Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732955/meteor-reactive-table-helper-arguments) but the comments on the post didn't help.

Html Code:

```
{{#each staffCode}}
   {{> reactiveTable collection=collectionDetails settings=settingsResult}}
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
collectionDetails: function(staffCode){
    return someCollection.find({staff_code: staffCode});
},
settingsResult: function(){
    return {
        rowsPerPage: 20,
        showFilter: false,
        showNavigation: 'auto',
        fields: [
        { 
            key: 'some_key', label: 'Some Label' ,
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

So far I tried putting

```
{{#each staffCode}}
    {{> reactiveTable collection=collectionDetails ../code settings=settingsResult}}
{{/each}}
```

But this doesn't work and gives the following error in the terminal

```
Can't have a non-keyword argument after a keyword argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those who have the same issue, I have solved the problem, here's the way I approached it.

```
{{#each staffCode}}
    {{#with collectionDetails code}}
        {{> reactiveTable collection=this settings=settingsResult}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```